# MySQL Column; split into two in resultset

Tags: mysql

We have a table structure we've inherited like so:

```
---------------------------------------------
option_id        title    option_type_id(FK)
---------------------------------------------
 1             Option1             1
 2             Option2             1
 3             Option3             2
 4             Option4             2
 5             Option5             3
```

The table above is the set of 'options' available in the system.

```
---------------------------------------------
 map_id        item_id         option_id(FK)
---------------------------------------------
   1             16378             1
   2             16378             4
   3             87680             2
   4             87680             3
   5             87680             5
```

The bottom table has a foreign key link to the top table, which maps out all the 'options' attached to each item.

The problem is that we ideally would like to show the dataset split per option, like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
 item_id       option_type_1      option_type2
-----------------------------------------------
    87680         Option2            Option3
```

Can anyone help? I've tried INNER JOINs and LEFT OUTER JOINs but nothing seem to quite cover all the possibilities. In this particular case, we're only concerned with option_types 1 and 2 for the result-set.

Comment: What you want is a pivot query, which mysql doesn't support. The workarounds get VERY VERY ugly VERY VERY fast as you want more columns auto-created, and the workarounds cannot dynamically adjust to more/less columns. This is better done in your client app.

Answer (score 0):

if all you are interested in is Option 1 & Option 2 then:

```
select item_id, o1.title, o2.title
from itemtable as IT
left join optiontable as O1 on it.option_id = o1.option_id and option_type_id = 1
left join optiontable as O2 on it.option_id = o1.option_id and option_type_id = 2
```